# delete query with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to delete a product from database with $http delete and I can't because I can't recover the id of the element in the table.

the code :
dans le controlleur :

```
@RequestMapping("/delete")

public boolean deleteProduit(Long Id)

{
 produitRepository.delete(Id);
 return true;
}
```

Dans html page :

```
<td >{{p.id}}</td>
<td>{{p.name}}</td>
<td>{{p.price}}</td>
<td>
<a class='btn btn-danger' href='' ng-click='supprim(produits.content)'>
Delete
</a>
```

dans js :

```
$scope.supprim = function(data){
$scope.produits.content=data;

var index = $scope.produits.content.indexOf(data);
var result = confirm('Are you sure to delete this product ? '); 

if(result===true)
{
alert($scope.produits.content.valueOf(id))

$http.delete("/delete?Id="+$scope.produits.content.id);
                    $scope.produits.content.splice(index, 1);
}
};
```

La page json est sous cette forme

> {"content":[{"id":5,"name":"pk25","price":125.0},{"id":6,"name":"pk25","price":125.0},{"id":7,"name":"pk25","price":125.0},{"id":8,"name":"pk25","price":125.0},{"id":9,"name":"pk25","price":125.0}],"totalPages":2,"totalElements":9,"last":false,"size":5,"number":0,"first":true,"sort":null,"numberOfElements":5}

I need help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited you post to fix English issues and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you must use @ResponseBody anotation in controller. so your code like this. 
this code is not complete. 
Spring controller code

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
   @ResponseBody
   public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id){    
   }
```

and your angularjs code like this

```
        var response = $http.delete('/delete/' + id)
          response.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          });
          response.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              alert('Error deleting ...');
           });
```

Comment: The problem is in this line  $http.delete('/delete/' + id)

Comment: the id in undefined . how can i recover the id